# "ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension" building Docker image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rubygems

I'm trying to build a Docker image based on ruby:3.0.  Inside Dockerfile, when running "RUN bundle install", start installing dependencies until error is shown:

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. #10
> 34.20 #10 34.20 current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.5/ext/tiny_tds #10 34.20
> /usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r #10 34.20
> ./siteconf20220804-7-s3hvms.rb extconf.rb #10 34.20 looking for
> freetds headers in the following directories: #10 34.20 -
> /opt/local/include #10 34.20 - /opt/local/include/freetds #10 34.20 -
> /usr/local/include #10 34.20 - /usr/local/include/freetds #10 34.20
> looking for freetds library in the following directories: #10 34.20 -
> /opt/local/lib #10 34.20 - /opt/local/lib/freetds #10 34.20 -
> /usr/local/lib #10 34.20 - /usr/local/lib/freetds

Normally this issue is solved installing linux distribution headers files that is using, but in this case, I am not know how do it.

Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM ruby:3.0

## throw errors if Gemfile has been modified since Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle config --global frozen 1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

RUN gem i bundler
RUN bundle install

COPY . .

CMD ["rails c"]
```

I tried adding this to Dockerfile, but another error was shown:

```
RUN apt-get install ruby-dev
```

[image]

Thank you very much in advance to whoever can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try building on the 3.0-buster image because I think that comes with additional packages. More info here: https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did, but the error is still showing.  FROM ruby:3.0-buster

Answer (score 0):

I run `RUN apt-get install ruby-dev` in Dockerfile and this issue is the same to you.

I change to bellow. Beside you can add other lib such as  `nodejs` `postgresql-client` ... I have consulted here https://docs.docker.com/samples/rails/

```
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    libpq-dev \
    ruby-dev
```

or

```
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y ruby-dev
```